# Send email through Wordpress with php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to send an email through WordPress with wp_mail.
I have a script as you can see below, resulting in "mail@mail.com" (a single string).
When i try to email that result with wp_mail, the mail is "Array" and not the string.

Can you assist me on that?
Below is my approach.

```
global $wpdb;
$client = "info@info.gr";
$subject = "TEST";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$sql="SELECT meta_value as Customer  FROM `wp_postmeta`  pm
inner join wp_posts p on pm.post_id = p.id
where p.id = 971
and pm.meta_key = `prefix-customermail`" ;

$last_link  = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

$message = " <html>
            <head>
            <title>Car Log</title>
            </head>
            <body>";
             $body = "<table class='TFtable' border='1' style='width':100%>"; //starts the table tag
            $body .= "<tr><td>Name</td></tr>"; //sets headings
            $body.= '<tr><td>'.$last_link.'</td></tr>';
            $body .= "</table>"; //closes the table
            $message .= $body . "
            </body>
            </html>";

wp_mail( $client, $subject, $message , $headers);
```

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: If you replace `$last_link` with `print_r($last_link, true)` in your email body, what does that data look like? It's presumably an array, and this will give you a clear idea of what you need to change in order to access the specific value you want from it.